# Sketching a complex region

Tags: complex-analysis

**Question:** Sketch the complex region given by the inequality:

$$|z-1|\lt|z+1|$$

**My attempt:**

I tried to square both sides and use the fact that $z=x+iy$ however upon expanding I got a form that I couldn't recognise as any shape

Comment: $|z-1|$ is the distance from $z$ to the point $1$ and $|z+1|$ is its distance to $-1$. The solutions of $|z-1|=|z+1|$ must be the points at the same distance of those points, i.e. the perpendicular bisector. Therefore the inequality is at one side of the perpendicular bisector.

Comment: So would the answer simply be the set of points from x=0 to x= $\infty$?

Comment: I'd probably describe it as $\mathcal{Re}(z)>0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of $|z-1|$ as the distance from a point
and 
$|z+1|$ is the distance from a different point

$|z-1|<|z+1|$ will be the set of points closer to $1+0i$ than they are to $-1+0i$

Comment: So would the answer simply be the set of points from x=0 to x= $\infty$?

Comment: Yes, everything with real part greater than $0.$

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track. Let $z=x+iy$ then expand
$$(x-1)^2+y^2=|(x-1)+iy|^2=|z-1|^2 < |z+1|^2=|(x+1)+iy|^2=(x+1)^2+y^2.$$
What is the inequality that we find at the end? Probably something went wrong in your expansion because the final inequality is very simple.

Comment: I think you are missing a $z$ on the first line.

Comment: @Junglemath Thanks for pointing out!

Answer (score 1):

As noted in a comment, this is much easier to do using geometry. The inequality literally says "$z$ is closer to $1$ than it is to $-1$". That gives us a half-plane.